# What does it mean in Swift: 'case .success(let dict):'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, promisekit

In Swift PromiseKit library there's Alamofire example using a bit strange syntax:

```
func login(completionHandler: (NSDictionary?, ErrorProtocol?) -> Void    {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let dict):
                completionHandler(dict, nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
        }
}
```

`response` is an Alamofire enum describing two cases with associated values:

```
public enum Result<Value> {
    case success(Value)
    case failure(Error) 
(...)
```

What I don't get is what does `let` mean in each `case:` line and where does the dict (or error) come from? Is this syntactic sugar for something more verbose but less confusing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Swift, enums can have associated values ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html)). This means, that you can associate an object with cases. The part `(let dict)` simply means - take the associated value, and put in in a `let` constant named `dict`.

Comment: Ok, so we're basically testing for enum being .success or .failure and the `(let xxx)` part is basically some kind of a shortcut getter for the associated value?

Comment: Correct. You can also write it as `case let .success(dict):`

Comment: Swift syntax doesn't cease to surprise me sometimes with shortcuts it allows. :-)

Comment: Also I'd swear I looked through the docs for enum associated values and it wasn't there but it clearly is. :-)

Comment: do anyone knows the difference between the two syntax 
 case let .success(value) vs case .success(let value)

Comment: The Enumerations document: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html look for Associated Values section it has a great explaination and example for Bar Codes.